# How to access External JS file from aspx code behind using ScriptManager in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JavaScript file separately in my project, and i wanted to call it from c# code behind using ScriptManager.

(My External Javascript file is a plugin.)

How can I do it? Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `RegisterStartupScript` to do this. Something like this should work:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "JavaScript", "javascript:function_name(); ", true);`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.

### Update

From your comments, it sounds like what you really want to do is dynamically load a JavaScript file from the code behind. This can be done by building a `script` element in the code behind and adding it to the page.

For example, given a script named `myFile.js`, you could do something like this:

```
var js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
js.Attributes["src"] = "myFile.js";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(js);
```

Comment: Thanks @AndroidNoobie...! But I want to call the whole JS file from code behind. Is it possible

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem. You can add a script to your page using `script` tags like any other HTML page: `<script src="foo.js"></script>`. The script will load when the page loads. You can then call any method from that script.

Comment: exactly...! But i wanted to call this script file `foo.js` only when certain function gets true from code behind.      How to do it? Thanks & regards....!

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you feel my answer was useful, feel free to mark it as accepted so others with the same question can more easily find it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using ScriptManager we can call the external JS file as follows:

`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "none", "<script src='foo.js' type='text/javascript'></script>", false);`

Here `foo.js` is my JS file which is my project, and this file can be called from back-end, when needed. In Page load it won't be called.